# How do I load table data in DIV for every row of ASP:Repeater control using JQuery $.post?

Tags: jquery, post, html

I want to LOAD table data from a database, and display it in a `<div>` tag for every row of `ASP:Repeater`, in the ItemTemplate, when the HTML page gets loaded.

I am trying it by jquery `$.post`, but I am not able to load in the `<div>` properly.

Comment: Can you post the code you have? Repeater template and $.post. Is your jquery post successfully returning data?